# HockeyApp SDK integration to PULL crash logs

Tags: ios, objective-c, hockeyapp, jira-mobile-connect

HockeyApp have their [iOS SDK](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/hockeyapp-for-ios) that allows you to do the following things

> The SDK allows testers to update your app to another beta version
> right from within the application. It will notify the tester if a new
> update is available. The SDK also allows to send crash reports. If a
> crash has happened, it will ask the tester on the next start whether
> he wants to send information about the crash to the server.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to create a standalone iOS application that can help you pull down all crash logs which match a particular criterion of Version and OS (eq iOS build # 567).

While digging into this I came across the [public API](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api) that can achieve the desired thing but in a lengthy fashion as I have it here.

1. STEP  1 Pull info for a specific Build Version  curl   -L -H
   "X-HockeyAppToken: API_TOKEN”
   https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/APP_ID/app_versions
2. STEP  2 If we want to pull all crash reasons for specific Build
   Version   curl   -L -H "X-HockeyAppToken: API_TOKEN"
   https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/APP_ID/app_versions/2/crash_reasons
3. STEP 3 - Iterate through all Crash Groups and If Crash Count > 0
   then pull down the crashes in that group curl   -L -H
   "X-HockeyAppToken: API_TOKEN"
   https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/APP_ID/crash_reasons/24365370
4. STEP 4 - Now fetch the Account info for a Particular Crash by
   passing the Crash ID curl   -L -H "X-HockeyAppToken: API_TOKEN"
   https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/APP_ID/crashes/2293834022?format=text

> Question

Is there a way to achieve the same using the official HockeyApp SDK ? The reason I have this question because `BITFeedbackListViewController` does have implementation that fetched the feedback/Crash. I have slightest doubt if these is even supposed to be used for Pulling down the crashes into iOS application.

Has anyone ever tried to achieve what I am trying ? If yes a few pointers could be really helpful to implement this.

> My next step is going to be JIRA integration to MAP - the crashes to
> JIRA tickets.
> and hence pulling the crashes down in the application is important.
> **NOTE:** JIRA-Mobile-Connect tag is added as this is the second step related to the question asked here. Please do not remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should contact HockeyApp support.
2. The answer to your question is: No.
3. The SDK is designed, implemented and meant to send crash reports to the server, not the other way round.
4. The feedback system in the SDK has nothing to do with crash reports.
5. You need to implement your own logic using the Public API for what you want to do.
6. For crashes of your own apps that get send to HockeyApp, you can connect your Jira instance on the website and create tickets from there without the need of an extra app.

Comment: The requirement of a separate application is because this is a Customer Care application that will allow executives to go through all user feedbacks (captured separately) for the application, PULL their crash logs (Hockeyapp) and create new tickets (JIRA) including the feedback provided for the app.I've got a clear idea with the steps that you mentioned and will work on that. Thanks